# Z-Function and unique substrings: broken algorithm parroted everywhere?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am not a huge math nerd so I may easily be missing something, but let's take the algorithm from https://cp-algorithms.com/string/z-function.html and try to apply it to, say, string `baz`. This string definitely has a substring set of 'b','a','z', 'ba', 'az', 'baz'.

Let's see how z function works (at leas how I understand it):

1. we take an empty string and add 'b' to it. By definition of the algo z[0] = 0 since it's undefined for size 1;
2. we take 'b' and add 'a' to it, invert the string, we have 'ab'... now we calculate z-function... and it produces {0, 0}. First element is "undefined" as is supposed, second element should be defined as:

`i-th element is equal to the greatest number of characters starting from the position i that coincide with the first characters of s.`

so, at i = 1 we have 'b', our string starts with a, 'b'  doesn't coincide with 'a' so of course z[i=1]=0. And this will be repeated for the whole word. In the end we are left with z-array of all zeroes that doesn't tell us anything despite the string having 6 substrings.

Am I missing something? There are tons of websites recommending z function for `count of distinct substrings` but it... doesn't work? Am I misunderstanding the meaning of `distinct` here?

See test case: https://pastebin.com/mFDrSvtm

Comment: When you see a web site that recommends using the Z function to get a count of distinct substrings, you have to read more of it to see *how* you're supposed to use the Z function to get a count of distinct substrings.  You may think that reading all the words is a waste of time, but really it's easier than writing a decent question on SO, and you'll probably find everything laid out for you better than an SO answer.

Comment: I have even typed out _exactly_ how I understand the application of the algo according to the site's words, _specifically_ so that people could correct me.

Comment: Ok, then, I'll write you an answer, but it sounds a lot like the one you linked to.  Maybe it will help to show how your example works.

Comment: `it sounds a lot like the one you linked to`



And that's exactly the problem. If my rewording sounds correct to you, then either they are missing something, or I am missing something. Because z-array, far as I understand, will be filled only for strings that have substrings  where their prefix after the string is inverted has something characters in common with suffix. `baz` and its parts, however you invert them as the algorithm is working, will have none of that and z array will stay empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add a character *x* to the beginning of a string *S*, all the substrings of *S* are still substrings of *xS*, but how many *new* substrings do you get?

- The new substrings are all prefixes of *xS*.  There are length(*xS*) of these, but
- max(Z(*xS*)) of these are already substrings of *S*, so
- You get length(*xS*) - max(Z(*xS*)) new ones

So, given a string S, just add up all the length(*P*) - max(Z(*P*)) for every suffix *P* of S.

Your test case `baz` has 3 suffixes: `z`, `az`, and `baz`.  All the letters are distinct, so their Z functions are zero everywhere.  The result is that the number of distinct substrings is just the sum of the suffix lengths: 3 + 2 + 1 = 6.

Try `baa`: The only non-zero in the Z functions is Z('aa')[1] = 1, so the number of unique substrings is 3 + 2 - 1 + 1 = 5.

Note that the article you linked to mentions that this is an O(n<sup>2</sup>) algorithm.  That is correct, although its overhead is low.  It's possible to do this in O(n) time by building a suffix tree, but that is quite complicated.

Comment: Okay, I see what I was doing wrong. Thank you. I assumed that z function needs to be filled or the algo isn't working properly. So it's length - Zmax that I misinterpreted because I thought z function isn't being applied properly where in fact empty function is perfectly fine.

That explanatory part about 3 suffixes is all I needed  to finally understand